# Studying MVC 4 MySQL Mono and need suggestions on authentication

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, mono

I'm currently studying how to deploy and run a full pledged ASP.Net MVC 4 site on Mono. Now, please don't get me wrong, I'm doing my best to do research on how to implement this. My first option was OAuth, but after some research, it seems that I might have some issues running it with MySQL.

So perhaps, I'm stuck with Simple forms authentication? I've seen some samples done in 2012 online which simply reuse the old authentication from MVC 3 and replace the one generated my MVC 4 projects.

I need your advice to which step to take best.

Cheers!